# Problem with SAMBA AD AUth

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, samba

I'm having an issue with SAMBA AD authentication. What i believe is happening, is that winbind is not able to see all of the users in my AD.

I can successfully query groups and domains with `wbinfo -u` and `wbinfo -g`, but when a user tries to authenticate, samba doesn't see them, and grepping for then in the output of `wbinfo -u` returns no results.

I have ~160k objects in AD, `wbinfo -u | wc -l` returns ~28k entries.

my smb.conf:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================

[global]

# Domain Authntication Settings
        workgroup = <my domain>
        server string = <Sever String>
        security = ads
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        realm = <mydomain.com>
        client use spnego = yes
        ldap ssl = no
# logging
        log level = 5
        max log size = 50
        # logs split per machine
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
;       max log size = 50

# User settings
        username map =  /etc/samba/smbusers
        idmap uid = 10000-20000000
        idmap gid = 10000-20000000
        idmap backend = ad
;       template primary group = <ad group>
        template shell = /sbin/nologin

# Winbind Settings
        winbind separator = +
        winbind enum users = Yes
        winbind enum groups  = Yes
        winbind netsted groups = Yes
        winbind nested groups = Yes
        winbind use default domain = Yes

#Other Globals
        unix charset = LOCALE
        server string = <my server name>
        load printers = no
        printing =  cups
        cups options = raw

;       printcap name = /etc/printcap
        #obtain list of printers automatically on SystemV
;       printcap name = lpstat
;       printing = cups


#============================ Share Definitions ==============================


[share]
comment = <share comment>
path = /srv/smb/share
guest ok = yes
valid users = "DOMAIN+testUser"
read only = yes
```

Any help, or pointers in the right direction - greatly appreciated!

Let me know if you need any log or other config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in the version of SAMBA in the ubuntu repository. I ended up grabbing the latest stable from samba's site and that cleared everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with a similar problem and my fix was to add the Samba machine into the "Builtin\Pre-Windows 2000  Compatible Access" group.  You also did not specify what version of Windows Server 2003.  This worked on SBS 2003 SP2.

Comment: It's a variety there are about 100 DC's throughout the infrastructure most of them are either 2k3 SP2 or 2k3 R2 SP2

Comment: Did you add the machine to the group, any luck?

Comment: I did add it to the group, haven't been able to test because it went into production (put basic unix users in place temporarily). I'm going to get a test rig up to duplicate the environment, if that works I'll give ya the answer.